# Setting pseudo-element dimensions in CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am currently attempting to set the :before pseudo element width, to match the dimensions of the element itself (in this case, an anchor tag), with the aim of creating an overlay which covers the entire element. To demonstrate, for this example, I will consider Google's web page for a demo:

```css
a.gb_g::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    content: 'hello';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="gb_h gb_i">
      <a class="gb_g" data-pid="23" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm&amp;ogbl">Gmail</a>
</div>
```

However, this produces the following result:

[image: Gmail and Images links from Google's web page - showing overlays with incorrect dimensions]

I have also attempted to set `width: 100%`, yet this results in container overflows. Is it possible to set the pseudo element width, to perfectly match that of the element itself (in this case, the 'Gmail'/'Images' link)? The desired result is for the overlay to fully cover each of the anchor tags, without making any CSS changes to the element itself.

Basically, I'm faced with a scenario where I have a fixed web page layout (with existing styling I have no control over), for which I would like to highlight parts of the web page (including some of the links). So, ideally any proposed solutions would cause minimal impact on the existing page layout, which is why I attempted to opt for an entirely pseudo-element based solution.

Comment: Are you sure you want to highlight using this principle? If your objective is to highlight only, why not for example add a background color to the element?

Comment: Tried that as well, yet different element padding/margins resulted in inconsistent highlighting (not very neat). I've also considered an approach with background-images, yet this does not work well across all cases either. Having said this, any other ideas are welcome @Mahatmasamatman.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? Adding position: relative to the element, and width: 100% to the pseudo element solved it for me.

```css
a.gb_g::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    content: 'hello';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

a.gb_g{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="gb_h gb_i">
      <a class="gb_g" data-pid="23" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm&amp;ogbl">Gmail</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ideally, I'd like this to work without any changes to the element's position property, as this would effect the layout of some elements in the web page. This is why I'm seeking to make changes to the width of the pseudo element itself, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but you can add "position: relative" for the actual element, then "width: 100%" for ::before. You can use "overflow: hidden" and "white-space: nowrap" to fully contain the pseudo element.

```css
a.gb_g {
    position: relative;
}
a.gb_g::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    content: 'overlay text long';
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div class="gb_h gb_i">
  <a class="gb_g" data-pid="23">Original Text</a> Next
</div>
```

Comment: As stated in the comment below, ideally, I'd like this to work without any changes to the element's position property, as this would effect the layout of some elements in the web page. This is why I'm seeking to make changes to the width of the pseudo element itself, if possible.

Comment: Add an extra class to the elements that you want to use this pseudo-overlay on, and apply the position to that extra class. Then it will not affect any other element.

Comment: What I mean is that 'position: relative' would impact the position of the element to which it is applied, which is undesirable. I am applying this pseudo element styling to already existing web pages, so I have no control over how the other CSS styling in the web page is laid out. So, I require a solution, whereby my changes will in no way break the layout of the existing web page.

Comment: @Questionnaire how position:relative on links will affect the layout? you need to make the containing block of the pseudo element to be the link or it won't be possible.

Comment: Agreed. Yes, changing the position property to relative for all links does break parts of the layout, as I've tried it already. Had this not been an issue, I would have opted for the suggested solution. Basically, I have a fixed web page layout (with existing styling I have no control over), for which I would like to highlight parts of the web page (including some of the links). So, I would like a solution which will cause minimal impact on the existing page layout @TemaniAfif.

Comment: @Questionnaire you won't find more minimal than using position:relative on links.